# What is a resolution in logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

(In "Introduction to mathematical logic" by mendelson , page 32)

I found this concept that I seemingly not been able to grasp , a resolution. It is represented by the function $Res(\beta)$ (Here $\beta$ is a cnf) . Now , I couldn't really understood this from the textbook itself. And , I tried to find this on the internet , but I only find "resolution proof" , which seems to be not related to what I wanted(I might be wrong). It is said in the book that $Res(\beta)$ is like a repetitive algorithm . But the algorithm itself seems to be unclear to me in many ways.

Can someone tell me if there is any books where they have more info about this algorithm for resolution?

Comment: See the post [Proving consequence by resolution refutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825722/proving-consequence-by-resolution-refutation)

Comment: See also [Application of the resolution method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130443/application-of-the-resolution-method)

Comment: $\mathcal {Res}(\mathcal B)$ is the result of applying the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) to a formula $\mathcal B$ in CNF. Using author's example: let $\mathcal B :=  (A \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot B) \land (C \lor D \lor A)$ and applying the rule with pair $C, \lnot C$, we get: $\mathcal {Res}(\mathcal B) :=  (A \lor \lnot B \lor D)$

Comment: The Resolution rule is an *inference rule* (similar to Cut rule) that we can rewrite as: if $\varphi \to c$ and $c \to \psi$, then $\varphi \to \psi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution rule in simplified notation is

$$(\ldots_1 \lor A \lor \ldots_2) \land \ldots \land (\ldots_3 \lor \neg A \lor \ldots_4)\\
\rightsquigarrow_\mathcal{R} (\ldots_1 \lor \ldots_2 \lor \ldots_3 \lor \ldots_4)$$

where the $\ldots$s are (possibly empty, but see below) disjunctions of literals.

This step is called resolution on $A$, and the conclusion of the rule is called the resolvent.

The resolution algorithm consists of simply repeating the resolution rule on the conjoined output of the previous steps until there are no more occurrences of literals $A, \neg A$ to resolve. The result of this is called $\mathcal{Res}(\mathcal{B})$: $\mathcal{Res}(\mathcal{B}) = \mathcal{B} \land \mathcal{R}_1 \land \ldots \land \mathcal{R}_n$, where each resolvent $\mathcal{R}_i$ is obtained by applying one resolution step on the previous result $\mathcal{B} \land \ldots \land \mathcal{R}_{n-1}$.

---

Resolution does have to do with resolution proof.

Mendelson requires the disjunctions formed from resolution to be non-empty, and calls the limit case of disjunctions consisting of only one resolvable literal "blatant contradictions". Normally one would define resolution also for this limit case, when the two disjunctions consist of only one literal before the resolution step and of zero literals afterwards,

$$(A) \land (\neg A)\\
\rightsquigarrow_\mathcal{R} \Box$$

$\Box$ is called the empty clause and is unsatisfiable; the idea being that a disjunction is true iff at least one of its disjuncts is true, and if the disjunction is empty, there is nothing to satisfy it, so it is contradictory.

A resolution proof of a formula $\mathcal{B}$ consisits of negating $\mathcal{B}$, forming its CNF, and applying the resolution iteration on it, i.e. computing $Res(CNF(\neg \mathcal{B})))$. If and only if the resolution procedure yields the empty clause, the negation of $\mathcal{B}$ is unsatisfiable, so $\mathcal{B}$ must be a tautology, and the derivation of the empty clause is a resolution proof of $\mathcal{B}$: $$\vDash \mathcal{B} \text{ iff } Res(CNF(\neg \mathcal{B}))) = \Box$$
This can be generalized to resolution proofs of inferences by performing the procedure on the conjunction between the unnegated premsies and the negated conclusion: $$\mathcal{A}_1, \ldots, A_n \vDash \mathcal{B} \text{ iff } Res(CNF(\mathcal{A_1} \land \ldots \land \mathcal{A}_n \land \neg \mathcal{B})) = \Box$$

The keyword for finding resources covering resolution is "logic programming"; one I have lying around is Kees Doets (1994), "From logic to logic programming". The style of presentation varies between different textbooks; Doets uses set notation instead of the $\lor$ connective for disjunctions and a tree-style presentation of derivations, others use a sequent notation $\vdash$ for the clauses, but the idea is all the same.

Comment: Isn't $Res(\beta)$ dependant on what $A$ you choose at first? And also , what  if $\beta$ was a cnf with more than $2$ conjunctives?

Comment: For resolution in propositional logic, the order in which you resolve the literals does not matter for the end result, if that was your question. Resolution can be applied across any two conjuncts of a CNF; the rule implicitly incorporates commutativity.